# I want to improve my algorithm of knowing eigenvalues of the matrix H(k)

Tags: plotting, matrix, performance-tuning, linear-algebra

I want to improve my algorithm. 
I want to know the eigenvalues of below n-dimensional matrix H. When n=10, the matrix H is like below.
[image]

Now, $To$ and $M$ are constants and $T1$ and $T2$ are functions as k.

$T1=2t_1\cos{\frac{k}{2}}$

$T2=2t_2\cos{\frac{k}{2}}$

$t1$ and $t2$ are constants. I want to know the eigenvalues of matrix H(k) each k numerically. And I want to plot the eigenvalues of H(k) as the function of k. So I wrote

```
n = 40;
M = 0.4;
Clear[X]
X = {{0, 0}};
For[k = -3.14, k < 6.28, k = k + 0.02,
To = 1.86;
T1 = 2*0.63*Cos[k/2];
T2 = 2*0.35*Cos[k/2];
H = 
Table[If[i == j + 1 && Mod[i, 2] == 0, T1, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}] +
Table[If[i + 1 == j && Mod[i, 2] == 1, T1, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}]+
Table[If[i == j && (Mod[i, 4] == 1 || Mod[i, 4] == 2), +M, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}] +
Table[If[i == j && (Mod[i, 4] == 3 || Mod[i, 4] == 0), -M, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}] +
Table[If[i == j + 1 && Mod[i, 2] == 1, To, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}] +
Table[If[i + 1 == j && Mod[i, 2] == 0, To, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}] +
Table[If[i == j + 3 && Mod[i, 2] == 1, T2, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}] +
Table[If[i + 3 == j && Mod[i, 2] == 0, T2, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}] ;
For[q = 1, q < n + 1, q++,X = Prepend[X, {k, Eigenvalues[N[H]][[q]]}]]]
```

Now, I can get eigenvalues of H each k numerically. I have a list of {k, eigenvalues}. So,

```
ListPlot[X]
```

finally, we can get the graph like below.

[image]

I want to improve my algorithm. When n is 100, it takes time. How should I improve my algorithm? I want to speed up the calculation.

I use Mathematica 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest speed-up comes from constructing `H` only once, not every time in the main loop.  I also avoided the `For` loop in saving your results, which repeatedly called `Eigenvalues`.

```
n = 100;
M = 0.4;
Clear[X, T1, T2]
X = {{0, 0}};
H = Table[If[i == j + 1 && Mod[i, 2] == 0, T1, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}] + 
 Table[If[i + 1 == j && Mod[i, 2] == 1, T1, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}] + 
 Table[If[i == j && (Mod[i, 4] == 1 || Mod[i, 4] == 2), +M, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}] + 
 Table[If[i == j && (Mod[i, 4] == 3 || Mod[i, 4] == 0), -M, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}] + 
 Table[If[i == j + 1 && Mod[i, 2] == 1, To, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}] + 
 Table[If[i + 1 == j && Mod[i, 2] == 0, To, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}] + 
 Table[If[i == j + 3 && Mod[i, 2] == 1, T2, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}] + 
 Table[If[i + 3 == j && Mod[i, 2] == 0, T2, 0], {i, n}, {j, n}];
For[k = -3.14, k < 6.28, k = k + 0.02, To = 1.86;
 T1 = 2*0.63*Cos[k/2];
 T2 = 2*0.35*Cos[k/2];
 ev = Eigenvalues[N[H]];
 X = Join[X, Transpose[{Table[k, {n}], ev}]]
]
```

takes only 0.57sec, with `n`=100.

```
ListPlot[X]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is a quick answer, maybe someone else can offer other improvements.

Comment: Thank you. But I have an error and it does not work. "Table::itform: 位置2における引数nは反復演算の正しい形式ではありません．" I use Mathematica 8.

Comment: Whoops, I guess that the form `Table[k, n]` was added after v.8.  I changed it to `Table[k, {n}]` above, which might work better.

Comment: Thank you!!! It works!!

Answer (score 3):

First, generate the appropriate number of values for `k` and the associated parameters namely `T1` and `T2`.

Next, in order to overcome the fact that the implemented approach re-constructs matrix `H` *for every instance of parameter `k`*, the `For` '*loop*' will be replaced by an appropriate and more efficient choice.

Namely, it seems reasonable to allow the main evaluation loop of *Mathematica* to take care of the various conditions required to construct matrix `H` (another solution would be to take advantage of the structure of `H` but that requires more effort and won't be pursued here, even though it might have potential performance benefits).

This solution, will generate the `Eigenvalues` of matrix `H` sequentially (as is the case in the code presented in the question) and finally will plot the list of eigenvalues.

Matrix `H` can be generated with one of the following equivalent ways (the last one seems to evaluate a little faster contrary to my presumption that the main loop would be more efficient):

Define separately the various cases that make up matrix `H`:

```
f[i_, j_] /; i == j + 1 && Mod[i, 2] == 0 := T1
f[i_, j_] /; i + 1 == j && Mod[i, 2] == 1 := T1
f[i_, j_] /; i == j && (Mod[i, 4] == 1 || Mod[i, 4] == 2) := M
f[i_, j_] /; i == j && (Mod[i, 4] == 3 || Mod[i, 4] == 0) := -M
f[i_, j_] /; i == j + 1 && Mod[i, 2] == 1 := To
f[i_, j_] /; i + 1 == j && Mod[i, 2] == 0 := To
f[i_, j_] /; i == j + 3 && Mod[i, 2] == 1 := T2
f[i_, j_] /; i + 3 == j && Mod[i, 2] == 0 := T2
f[i_, j_] := 0
```

or-more or less-equivalently:

```
g[i_, j_] := T1 /; i == j + 1 && Mod[i, 2] == 0
g[i_, j_] := T1 /; i + 1 == j && Mod[i, 2] == 1
g[i_, j_] := M /; i == j && (Mod[i, 4] == 1 || Mod[i, 4] == 2)
g[i_, j_] := -M /; i == j && (Mod[i, 4] == 3 || Mod[i, 4] == 0)
g[i_, j_] := To /; i == j + 1 && Mod[i, 2] == 1
g[i_, j_] := To /; i + 1 == j && Mod[i, 2] == 0
g[i_, j_] := T2 /; i == j + 3 && Mod[i, 2] == 1
g[i_, j_] := T2 /; i + 3 == j && Mod[i, 2] == 0
g[i_, j_] := 0
```

or by using [`Which`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Which.html?q=Which):

```
h[i_, j_] := Which[
  i == j + 1 && Mod[i, 2] == 0, T1,
  i + 1 == j && Mod[i, 2] == 1, T1,
  i == j && (Mod[i, 4] == 1 || Mod[i, 4] == 2), M,
  i == j && (Mod[i, 4] == 3 || Mod[i, 4] == 0), -M,
  i == j + 1 && Mod[i, 2] == 1, To,
  i + 1 == j && Mod[i, 2] == 0, To,
  i == j + 3 && Mod[i, 2] == 1, T2,
  i + 3 == j && Mod[i, 2] == 0, T2,
  True, 0
 ]
```

Finally, use the eigenvalues of `H` to produce the required plot:

```
With[{n = 40},
  Module[{rng = Range[n], evs},

     (* generate matrix H *once* *)
     H[T1_, T2_] = Outer[h[##] &, rng, rng] /. Thread[{M -> 0.4, To -> 1.86}];

     (* for successive values of k, replace appropriate values for 
        T1 an T2, obtain the eigenvalues and assign k as the 
        x-coordinate *)
     evs = Table[
       Thread[
         {k, Eigenvalues[H[T1, T2] /. {T1 -> 2 0.63 Cos[k/2], T2 -> 2 0.35 Cos[k/2]}]}], 
      {k, -3.14, 6.28, 0.02}];

     (* produce separate plots for the n-th eigenvalue *)
     Grid[
       Partition[
         MapIndexed[
           ListPlot[#1, PlotLabel -> Row[{"eigenvalue", Null, #2[[-1]]}]] &,
           Transpose[evs]], 5, 5, {1, 1}, Null]]
    ]
  ]
```

[image]